# responsive columns not working?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Having trouble with my responsive layout. My twelve columns blocks are not on one row the last two float under it but should be all in one line.

Each row will be having its own column blocks.

You can get full code view of what I mean at my codepen snippet.
http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/zbmLE

```
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 94%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 2% auto 0 auto;
}

.row {
  display: block;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  min-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.block-1 {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}

.block-2 {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}

.block-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.block-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}

.block-5 {
  width: 41.66666667%;
}

.block-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.block-7 {
  width: 58.33333333%;
}

.block-8 {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}

.block-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.block-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}

.block-11 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}

.block-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.last, .omega, .end{
  margin: 0; 
}
```

Comment: I've got a responsive grid layout with LESS in progress here: http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/zpAiK. Maybe it helps

Comment: It's a LESS with flexible columns count. Just edit the less variables (identified by `@`) in the middle column and then click on the `CSS (LESS)` above and you will get the full CSS code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the margin on the columns:

```
.column {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  min-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px; <!-- remove -->
}
```

Instead of the reaching `100%` width the margin is causing less width for them due to the `20px` x 12. So your getting `100% + 240px`, this is causing the last 2 to move below.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tvKJz)

Comment: You can use padding if you want some spacing between the content of the columns, e.g. `padding: 0 10px 0`

Comment: Someone care to explain the down-vote? Its nice to know where I went wrong and how I can improve.

Comment: @Ruddy I need spacing between the column blocks.

Comment: @kiwi83 Your question was to get them all on the same line. Thats how you do it. If you want spaces you will have to make there widths smaller and add a margin back in.

Comment: I have been told in the past that the first column should allways be 8.333% I am using bootstraps widths. But trying to make my own.

Comment: @kiwi83 Bootstrap uses `width: 8.33333333%;` and `padding-left: 15px; 
padding-right: 15px;` if you don't want the background to apply to the gap use an extra div for your content. Or you could use `margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 1%; width: 6.33333333%`

Comment: Found a grid system that can help me for what I am after. Just to get me started. Great to get your advice.

Comment: @kiwi83 Great! Need any more help please do leave another question. :)

Comment: Looks Great but have looked at don't over think it grids. Making my own changes http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/ my code pen version here. http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/gqLzK

Answer (score 0):

Ruddy is right, you are not considering the gutter between columns. Do his way **or**...

**SIMPLE SOLUTION:**

Try to subtract 2% from each block class, worked here.

**FANCY SOLUTION:**

If you use LESS you can work with variables, so you could do something like this:

```
/*LESS FILE*/

@gutter: "20px";

.block1 {
   width: (8.333% - @gutter);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So use the 2% option and keep your margin.